# Are there any downsides to doing a schema migration in my post_compile script

Tags: django, heroku, django-south

I have a django app running on heroku. I would like to run my South migrations before any code that depends on them goes live. After a quick review of current recommended practices I have found two suggested migration procedures.

#### Recommendation 1

1. Commit and push all changes
2. Run `heroku run python manage.py migrate <APP_NAME>` for each app

This suffers from having a period in between steps 1 and 2 where my code is assuming the latest schema is in place, but the db hasn't yet been updated.

#### Recommendation 2

1. commit and push all database changes.
2. Migrate.
3. Push all code changes.

This solves the previous problem, but adds a lot more complexity to the deployment process, and some day I will mess this up.

#### Potential Solution?

It seems that I can avoid the problem in Recommendation 1 *and* keep my deployment to a single step by utilising a custom post_compile script
 that calls `python $MANAGE_FILE migrate <APP_NAME>` for each of my apps (in dependency order).

I have not seen this recommended anywhere, so my question is twofold. Can you see any potential problem with this approach, and do you have a better method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your application can afford some downtime, the easiest way seems to me to

1. Pause your app using `$ heroku maintenance:on`
2. Migrate all the apps at once with `heroku run python manage.py migrate`
3. Restart your app: `$ heroku maintenance:off`

Is it enough or do you have more complex needs ?

Comment: A bit of downtime isn't the end of the world for this, but if it is possible to avoid it I would obviously prefer that approach. I will definitely be using maintenance mode for any big, or backwards-incompatible changes.

Comment: I would also prefer to have the exact same deployment procedure for pure code changes and code change + minor schema change

Comment: I understand, but I don't really think you should distinct minor schema changes from "big changes". To me, as long as the schema and code changes at the same time, they should be executed atomically from the app standpoint. The cost of doing otherwise (inconsistency risk and/or adding much more complexity) surpass the benefit (no apparent downtime) in the vast majority of cases.

Comment: I disagree. For example adding an extra nullable column to a table is a much safer operation than changing the type of an existing column. The former will be compatible with old code and new, the latter will break all old code. I want my schema migration process to be the same either way, the only difference being that I will turn on maintenance mode for the latter but not the former